# Ironpython wpf RichTextBox

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, ironpython

How do you retrieve the contents of a RichTextBox in ironpython?
XAML:

```html
<RichTextBox
            x:Name = "Sheet_Name"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.Row="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Margin="174,62,0,0"
            Width="348"
            Height="476" />
```

This is the ironpython:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('System.Windows.Forms')
clr.AddReference('IronPython.Wpf')
from pyrevit import script
xamlfile = script.get_bundle_file('ui.xaml')
import wpf
from System import*
class MyWindow(Windows.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        wpf.LoadComponent(self, xamlfile)

    def Create_Sheets(self,sender,args):
        RTB = self.Sheet_Number
        TR = TextRange(RTB.Document.ContentStart, RTB.Document.ContentEnd).Text
    def Help(self,sender,args):
        print('Help')

MyWindow().ShowDialog()
```

The above method does not work as TextRange is not defined.

**Edit:**
above works if the following is imported:

```
from System.Windows.Documents import TextRange
```

Comment: [This post](https://markheath.net/post/wpf-and-mvvm-in-ironpython) describes in detail how to do Model-View-ViewModel data binding in WPF using IronPython, which is probably the best way to do it.

Comment: That said, [this post](https://livebook.manning.com/book/ironpython-in-action/chapter-9/41) seems to suggest that code-behind works the same way it does in any other language, so if you want you're code diagnosed, you need to show it to us.  Read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to Create a Minimal-Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for guidance.